# the size of PDF file generate with QWebEnginePage::printToPdf is too large

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm using the QWebEnginePage::printToPdf to convert HTML to PDF,but the file generated is too large.
The html file is only 100KB and no image in it, but the PDF file is 15,000KB.
Here is the code:

```
QWebEnginePage *WebEnginePage = new QWebEnginePage(this);
WebEnginePage->load(QUrl("file:///test.html"));
connect(WebEnginePage, &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, [=]()
    {
        WebEnginePage->printToPdf("test.pdf");
    });
```

The Qt version is 5.15.2.

How do I reduce the PDF file size?

Comment: I imagine it's drawing the character glyphs instead of just putting in the raw text, doesn't look like there are any options to control that on `printToPdf` though

Comment: @Alan There are some options to set layout and pagesize,but don't have effect on the file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printToPdf` doesn't allow you to control the printing however there is a separate [`print`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#print) method which allows you to use your own printer.

`QPrinter` has [`setFontEmbeddingEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setFontEmbeddingEnabled) and [`setOutputFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setOutputFormat) which allow you to control the output.

Something like this might improve your file sizes (untested):

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::ScreenResolution);
printer.setOutputFilename("test.pdf");
printer.setFontEmbeddingEnabled(true);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
WebEnginePage->print(&printer, resultCallback);
```

Notes:

- `QWebEnginePage::print` has been removed for some reason in Qt 6 so if you plan to upgrade in the future this might not be the best solution
- You might need to experiment with the output format, for example for me, on macos `QPrinter::PdfFormat` results in a rasterised PDF (probably the same as you're getting now) but `QPrinter::NativeFormat` produces a textual one. But on Windows `QPrinter::PdfFormat` is the better option.
- There is also a note in the `QWebEnginePage::print` documentation that it rasterises when sending to the printer so it may end up with the same result as you have now anyway

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and the pdf file is only 100KB!(Seems like the two methods generate two different kind of PDF files: vector PDF and raster PDF. Even so, the difference of size surprised me.)Anyway, thanks a lot, you helped me a lot!